# how to load a img from static folder in python-Django

Tags: css, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I try to build a portfolio website using html, css, js and django but i don't know how to load an image from assets in static folder.

This is the template code part:

```
{% load static%}
...
<div class="col-lg-5 align-items-stretch order-1 order-lg-2 img" 
    style='background-image: url("assets/img/why-us.png");' 
    data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="150">&nbsp;</div>
```

Other images get loaded but not this one. Instead I get a `Syntax error`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need no make sure that the static files are configured correctly in `settings.py` , check to see if you can find `STATIC_URL = 'static/'` in your `settings.py`. If not, add it at the end in a new line.

Then, the next step requires you to create a folder named `static` , or whatever you defined `STATIC_URL` to be in `settings.py` , in the app folder where you wish to use those static files. You will store all your static files in there.

Finally, to use your static files in the template, you need to use the `{% static '_FILEPATH_' %}` tag, without adding `static/` to the pathname.

PS: Make sure to `{% load static %}` **before** calling any static files

Ex: If I want to load a stylesheet in my template, my stylesheet will be located in `BASEDIR/APPNAME/static/style.css` and my `<head>` would look like this:

```html
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="{% static 'style.css' %}">
</head>
```

For any other issue try to refer to the Django documentation: [How to manage static files - Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Thank you su much man for your answer but i do all what you say before, but all elements are loaded Except this image above